# ASP.NET MVC FileResult with specific Filename and Safari or Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, safari, fileresult

I'm having problems with FileResult returning a file with a specific filename. In the database the filename is just and ID + extension (e.g: 456789.mp3)

This piece of code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
return File(fs, "application/octet-stream", "myfile.mp3");
```

Work well in every browser except Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari). Chrome and Safari receive files as original filename (456789.mp3). When I add headers with

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile.mp3");
```

Safari receives the file as myfile.mp3attach (notice "attach" appended to the extension?), however Chrome receives this file as myfile.mp3,attach (it appends ",attach" to the extension)

Has anyone experienced this kind of a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It has helped me:

```
        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Charset = encoding.WebName;
        Response.HeaderEncoding = encoding;

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE") ? HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, encoding) : fileName));

        return File(fs, contentType, fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
         Response.Clear();
         Response.ClearHeaders();
```

Before

```
         Response.Charset = encoding.WebName;
```

solved this for me